# What does it "mean" for two orthogonal vases of a vector space to be continguous?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, definition, quadratic-forms

In Serre's arithmetic he introduces an equivalence relation on the orthogonal bases of a quadratic module $(V,Q)$ through the use of continguity. Recall that a basis $e_1,\ldots, e_k$ of a quadratic module is called orthogonal if there is a direct sum decomposition
$$
k\cdot e_1\oplus \cdots \oplus k\cdot e_k
$$
such that
$$
Q(e_i,e_j) = a_{ij}\delta_{ij}
$$
Then, he calls two bases
$$
\begin{align*}
\underline{e} = (e_1,\ldots,e_k)&& \underline{e}'=(e_1',\ldots,e_k')
\end{align*}
$$
**contiguous** if there is some $e_j=e'_j$. He then goes on to prove in theorem 2 that every pair of orthogonal bases can be identified using a sequence/chain of contiguous bases.

My question is: does this contiguity property have any additional interpretation other than "just a tool" for proving the theorem?

Comment: I've never heard of orthogonal vases. Bases, on the other hand..

Comment: @Lovsovs see https://www.google.com/search?q=orthogonal+vases&client=browser-ubuntu&hs=XsD&channel=fe&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi42K2A67bUAhVX02MKHeazDxgQ_AUICigB&biw=1139&bih=602

Comment: My guess:Just a tool.

Comment: @WillJagy I may just have to keep the title now ;D

Comment: @Lubin I think you have it. See https://www.google.com/search?q=orthogonal+vises&client=browser-ubuntu&channel=fe&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw16fx-7bUAhUV1GMKHaHuBhgQ_AUIBigB&biw=1139&bih=602